# user-init-file Variable Value Doesn't Change

Tags: init-file

**The Goal**

Place everything related to `emacs` in `~/.config/.emacs.d`

**What I Have Done**

- Created `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.el` which contain the following code:

```
(setq user-init-file "~/.config/.emacs.d/init.el")
(setq user-emacs-directory "~/.config/.emacs.d")
(load user-init-file)
```

[Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)

**The Outcome**

- `emacs` still creates `~/.emacs.d` which contains the `auto-save-list` directory.
- Changing the value of variables through `M-x customize` creates the `~/.emacs` file.
- Examining the value of variables modified within `site-start.el` I get the following result:

```
user-init-file is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is "~/.emacs"

user-emacs-directory is a variable defined in ‘subr.el’.
Its value is "~/.config/.emacs.d"
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want? This is part of my effort to organize my `HOME` directory. I have read the following [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.  Emacs doesn't care if you've (unexpectedly) set `user-init-file` -- it looks for your init file in the places it's hard-coded to look for it, and it then *sets* `user-init-file` to the path of the init file it located.

*However* if you wait for Emacs 27 (or try a pretest release; currently 27.0.90 at time of writing), it essentially provides what you're looking for.

See the [NEWS](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS?h=561e9fb91bba98616f6d7ea3818727c1cdd2d853#n161) for details:

> Emacs can now use the XDG convention for init files.
>   The 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME' environment variable (which defaults to
>   "~/.config") specifies the XDG configuration parent directory.  Emacs
>   checks for "init.el" and other configuration files inside the "emacs"
>   subdirectory of 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME', i.e. "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/emacs/init.el"
>
> However, Emacs will still initially look for init files in their
>   traditional locations if "~/.emacs.d" or "~/.emacs" exist, even if
>   "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/emacs" also exists.  This means that you must delete
>   or rename any existing "~/.emacs.d" and "~/.emacs" to enable use of
>   the XDG directory.
>
> If "~/.emacs.d" does not exist, and Emacs has decided to use it
>   (i.e. "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/emacs" does not exist), Emacs will create it.
>   Emacs will never create "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/emacs".
>
> Whichever directory Emacs decides to use, it will set
>   'user-emacs-directory' to point to it.